# Receiving "InvalidOperationException:" in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a simple Asp.NET MVC database where a user can create an account, create categories for recipes, and then enter their recipe and file them into the category of their choosing.  However, when I attempt to run the test to see if I can reach my list of categories(where I can also add a category), I get the following error message:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'LC101Project2017.Data.RecipeDbContext' while attempting to activate 'LC101Project2017.Controllers.CategoryController'.

I'm new to C# and am completely confused as to what I'm doing wrong. Here are my codes:

**Controller:** (CategoryController.cs)

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly RecipeDbContext context;

    public CategoryController(RecipeDbContext dbContext)
    {
        context = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<RecipeCategory> categories = context.Categories.ToList();

        return View(categories);
    }

    public IActionResult Add()
    {
        AddCategoryViewModel addCategoryViewModel = new AddCategoryViewModel();

        return View(addCategoryViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(AddCategoryViewModel addCategoryViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RecipeCategory newCategory = new RecipeCategory
            {
                Name = addCategoryViewModel.Name
            };

            context.Categories.Add(newCategory);
            context.SaveChanges();

            CategoryController:  return Redirect("/Category");
        };
        return View(addCategoryViewModel);
    }
}
```

**Database** (RecipeDbContext.cs)

```
public class RecipeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**MODEL** (RecipeCategory.cs)

```
public class RecipeCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<RecipeCategory> RecipeCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? what .net framework version?

Comment: How are you doing your Dependency Injection? Are you doing .NET Core or regular .NET Framework?

Comment: I'm using the latest for both MVC and.net framework. I think MVC is 5.2.3 and Entity is 2.2.0.

As far as Dependency Injection, I'm honestly not sure how to answer that. I believe I'm using .NET Core, but I honestly am not 100% sure.  Like I said, total newbie.  =/

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have configured to use your DbContext, RecipeDbContext, inside ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

The method should look like this;

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<RecipeDbContext >(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName")));
    }
```

---

*Updated the answer in response to the comment by @Mel Mason*

You need to declare a constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions<RecipeDbContext>`.

```
    public class RecipeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RecipeCategory> Categories { get; set; }

        public RecipeDbContext(DbContextOptions<RecipeDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
    }
```

You can also check the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and got this error: System.ArgumentException: 'AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'RecipeDbContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to AddDbContext will never be used. If configuration is passed to AddDbContext, then 'RecipeDbContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions<RecipeDbContext> and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

Comment: That is because RecipeDbContext does not have the constructor, like `public RecipeDbContext(DbContextOptions<RecipeDbContext> options) : base(options){} `